# Вверхняя панель конфликует с картинкой

Tags: html, css

У меня есть такой код панели:

```css
.topnav {
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 55px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: white;
}

.settings {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href=""><b><i>Главная</i></b></a>
  <a href=""><b><i>Магазин</i></b></a>
  <a href=""><b><i>О нас</i></b></a>
  <a href=""><b><i>Инструменты</i></b></a>
  <a href="#zatemnenie"><img src="../img/set.png" class="settings" alt="Что то не так..." style="border: none"></a>
</div>
```

То есть, у меня есть картинка которая указывает на класс, без тега `<a>` у меня этого не получится. Но данная панель, работает с эти тегом, и получается так, что панель делает картинку кнопкой, то есть делает ее больше и сдвигает ее влево. Есть проблему обойти, так чтобы не выносить из дива `topnav`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать в стилях не на сколько *жадные* селекторы. Если вместо `.topnav a` делать стилизацию по определённому классу, например, по классу `navlink`, то стилизованными будут только ссылки с этим классом. В таком случае ссылка с картинкой никак не будет стилизоваться.

```css
.topnav {
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav .navlink {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 55px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.topnav .navlink:hover {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .navlink.active {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: white;
}

.settings {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="navlink active" href=""><b><i>Главная</i></b></a>
  <a class="navlink" href=""><b><i>Магазин</i></b></a>
  <a class="navlink" href=""><b><i>О нас</i></b></a>
  <a class="navlink" href=""><b><i>Инструменты</i></b></a>
  <a href="#zatemnenie"><img src="../img/set.png" class="settings" alt="Что то не так..." style="border: none"></a>
</div>
```